# Nautilus window buttons disappear when maximized

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 18.04, window-buttons

On a freshly updated Ubuntu 18.04 (Gnome 3.28.2), I used Gnome tweak tools to move window buttons to the left (`'close,maximize,minimize:'`). All applications seem fine, except Nautilus where the buttons disappear when I maximize the window. Restarting the shell with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd> does not help.

It is fully reproducible and does not occur when the buttons are on the right-hand side (see the screenshots).

Buttons on the left
[image: Buttons on the left]
***No*** buttons on the left when maximized
[image: No buttons on the left when maximized]
Buttons on the right
[image: Buttons on the right]
Buttons on the right when maximized
[image: Buttons on the right when maximized]

**EDIT:**
The question is obvious. What should I do to display the buttons on the left when maximized?

Comment: What’s your question? What are you trying to achieve? (Please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information. It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.) Thanks.

Comment: For some maximized windows I need to left click on the stray and drag down to achieve non-maximized.

Comment: Can't reproduce this. Do you have some extensions installed?

Comment: These are the extensions that I have: `['dropbox@orcinus4627.gmail.com', 'places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com', 'mediaplayer@patapon.info', 'system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com', 'drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com', 'replace-system-alt-switcher@emilio.sanchez.gmail.com', 'user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com', 'disconnect-wifi@kgshank.net', 'suspend-button@laserb', 'workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com']`

Comment: To debug, try if the problem persists after disabling all extensions (and after restarting your system). If the problem persists, then it may be worth trying to reset all your dconf settings to factory default (command: dconf reset -f /).

Comment: Nope. I have disabled all extensions and even after restart, the window buttons are not showing in Nautilus.

Comment: I hinted also to resetting your user config. You do no have to lose these settings if you export them before the reset. As an alternative, perhaps easier, create a new user, and check whether the issue persists there. Problem is: nobody apparently can reproduce your issue, so it is something particular in your config.

Comment: Also: post the output of "gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout" so we see exactly what string is stored there.

Comment: When on the right, it reads `':minimize,maximize,close'` and on the left, it reads `'close,maximize,minimize:'` as I have already written in the question.

Comment: also: I have done the reset and the buttons in Nautilus are still not there when set to the left and maximized.

Comment: Again, I can't reproduce even resetting my desktop to the Ubuntu default, so it is you who will need to keep debugging, and I can only throw some hints. A next hint is to disable all extensions you added yourself, and restarting gnome shell. Also create a new user and see if the problem also occurs under a new account if you did not do so already. It is a matter of trying to isolate where the error could be.

Comment: I get it, so let's recap: with or without extensions, after resetting gnome-shell to defaults and even with a new user, the problem remains. Do you have any other hints? Except for a clean install which I will NOT do.

Comment: Wait! Problem solved. But I do not know how or when... I have just installed the software updates and rebooted my computer afterwards. Then I tried to set it again to the left and it works even for maximized windows. Mystery...

Comment: I have the same problem and don't know how to solve it :-(